# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requirements

I am getting errors please tell me what is wrong with this, I am not able to find a solution anywhere!

I am working on one project but when other members try with install -r rquirements.txt they get this error! please tell what should be the action to handle or remove this error?

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] 
No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\ketan\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.21.2.dist-info\\ME
TADATA'
```

Output :

```
Collecting Werkzeug==2.0.2
Using cached Werkzeug-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel==0.37.0 in c:\users\ketan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 93)) (0.37.0)
Collecting win32-setctime==1.0.3
  Using cached win32_setctime-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (3.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: wincertstore==0.2 in c:\users\ketan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 95)) (0.2)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\ketan\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.21.2.dist-info\\ME
TADATA'
```

pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed

Output2 :

```
Collecting tbb==2021.*
  Using cached tbb-2021.4.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (268 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: bottleneck
  Building wheel for bottleneck (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\ketan\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\ketan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\keta
n\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4t2qkb8i'
       cwd: C:\Users\ketan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sqrcce6s\bottleneck_b15ec4cdd7084e748dc7a963008d04b3
  Complete output (51 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck
  copying bottleneck\_pytesttester.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck
  copying bottleneck\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck
  copying bottleneck\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\autotimeit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench_detailed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\benchmark
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\move.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce_axis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\reduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\slow
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\src
  copying bottleneck\src\bn_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\src
  copying bottleneck\src\bn_template.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\src
  copying bottleneck\src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\src
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\input_modification_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\list_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\memory_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\move_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_axis_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\reduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\scalar_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck\tests
  UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck/_version.py
  set build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bottleneck/_version.py to '1.3.2'
  running build_ext
  running config
  compiling '_configtest.c':
  
  
  
  int __attribute__((optimize("O3"))) have_attribute_optimize_opt_3(void*);
  
  int main(void)
  {
      return 0;
  }
  
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bottleneck
Failed to build bottleneck
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bottleneck which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

pip install numpy==1.19.3
Output3:

```
$ pip install numpy==1.19.3
Collecting numpy==1.19.3
  Using cached numpy-1.19.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (13.3 MB)
WARNING: Error parsing requirements for numpy: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\ketan\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.21.2.dist-info\\METADATA
'
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.21.2
ERROR: Cannot uninstall numpy 1.21.2, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.21.2'.
```

Comment: What command are you running? What's the _full_ output?

Comment: pip install -r requirements.txt : @ForceBru

Comment: @ketangangal Can you try `pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Now i am getting very large error , see output 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an older version of NumPy, it should work.

```
pip uninstall numpy

pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

Comment: i am getting this ERROR: Cannot uninstall numpy 1.21.2, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.21.2'

Comment: Try the force reinstall `pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.19.3`

Answer (score 0):

When using Windows OS with python, many python packages and libraries required Microsoft Build Tools for compiling and installing the package. You have to download [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) for installing Microsoft Build Tools. In addition also install C++ dependencies in Visual Studio.